# JAX-RS add headers to chunked response

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm having some trouble with my REST API service on my JBOSS 7.1.1 server.
Right now I use a RESTEasy implementation and I have the following filter to add CORS headers to the response:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "HeaderFilter", urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class HeaderFilter implements Filter {

    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException{}
    public void destroy(){}

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        //Just continue the request
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

        //After the request add the response headers
        HttpServletResponse responseObj = (HttpServletResponse)response;
        responseObj.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        responseObj.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        responseObj.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-Length");
    }
}
```

My problem is that the server sometimes chooses to send the response in parts.
Via the Transfer-Encoding: chunked "protocol".
This doesn't matter and I have no problem with that but it doesn't add the CORS headers anymore when it does this. The client side of the application is now unable to use the data and I cannot figure out how to add the CORS headers to the final response.

Do you guys know how I could fix this issue?

**EDIT:** I'm using Jackson to turn my lazy loaded model into JSON by the way, so I don't think it's as easy as just setting the Content-Length.

Comment: Are you sure that the first chunk does not have the CORS headers?

Comment: I am not, the first chunk will probably have those headers because the filter does run, I've tested this with a SYSOUT message. The problem however is that the result of the request does not have the proper headers, they do for example not show up in my dev http client and not on the JS application that consumes the data. @AndreiI

Comment: @Jcocqvan, did you find any solution for this? I am facing similar issue now.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.If transfer-encode is chunked, the response header is not editable after `filterChain.doFilter`.So `responseObj.addHeader` after that not edit the response header.So you must do it before `doFilter`.Like this

```java
@WebFilter(filterName = "HeaderFilter", urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class HeaderFilter implements Filter {

    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException{}
    public void destroy(){}

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        //Before the request add the response headers
        HttpServletResponse responseObj = (HttpServletResponse)response;
        responseObj.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        responseObj.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        responseObj.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-Length");

        //Just continue the request
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

        
    }
}
```